# Android - SQLite bindargs don't get used

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to run the following query using bindargs but it seems like they aren't being put into the query.

```
String questionWhereClause = Article.COL_CATEGORY_ID + " = ? AND " + Article.COL_TOPIC_ID + " = ? AND " + Article.COL_QUESTION_ID + " = ?";
String[] questionSelectionArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(category.getId()), Integer.toString(topic.getId()), Integer.toString(question.getId()) };

Cursor cursor = mDBConnection.query(Article.TABLE_NAME, null, questionWhereClause , questionSelectionArgs , null, null, null);

// Use cursor here
```

If I replace the `?` with appropriate values the cursor returns fine. When I go to use `cursor.moveToNext()` with the `bindargs` there are no items in the cursor. When I look at the cursor object the value under `mCompiledSqlStatement` still has the `?` marks in it as well. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove the space after the `=` so that it looks like `=?`

Comment: I tried that as well as removing the space prior to the = sign and it still doesn't work

Comment: remove spaces before and after the equals sign though, basically get the statement to look like `ID=? AND...`

Comment: I tried it both ways, with or without spaces makes no difference

Comment: I found the arguments binding only work with String columns, which was a bit of a let-down. If I am mistaken I would be glad to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference of [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) says:

> You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. **The values will be bound as Strings.**

I'm guessing that this last bit about the values bound as Strings could be the cause of the issue somehow.

In any ase I have a workaround for you: use the `rawQuery` method instead, crafting your SQL string like this:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %d AND %s = %d AND %s = %d",
     Article.TABLE_NAME, 
     Article.COL_CATEGORY_ID, category.getId(),
     Article.COL_TOPIC_ID, topic.getId(),
     Article.COL_QUESTION_ID, question.getId());
```

This is not as efficient as binding the parameters (since here we cannot benefit from prepared statements), but for all practical purposes, it's probably good enough. I use this style quite a lot, as I find it easier to read.

**Update**

The equivalent of the following also works for me in one of my apps:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ? AND %s = ? AND %s = ?",
     Article.TABLE_NAME, 
     Article.COL_CATEGORY_ID, 
     Article.COL_TOPIC_ID, 
     Article.COL_QUESTION_ID);
String args = new String[] { category.getId(), topic.getId(), question.getId() };
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, args);
```

That is, binding arguments works for me, whether they are text columns or integer columns. I hope you can get it to work too.

Comment: I actually like this method better as you can see the exact SQL string being submitted, which is handly when its late and you're debugging SQL errors.

Comment: I agreed raw query is nice for seeing the full statement laid out but my issue lies with too many statements in the queue so the system suggests that I use bindargs to prevent loss of data. I guess I might have to do it this way and with smaller chunks of statements.

Comment: @DMan maybe do a simple isolated test, binding a single param for a WHERE clause on a text column, and another on an int column. It looks like this doesn't work for int columns, in which case you simply don't have a choice.

Comment: @janos Great suggestion. I just took this for a spin and unfortunately it didn't work for either. I don't believe I am doing it wrong either so I'm a little confused as to what is going wrong. I have reverted back to the precompiled statements so I'll just have to do it in a smaller chunk.

Comment: @DMan Actually I found a working example in one of my apps, where I bind arguments, sometimes to text valued columns, sometimes integer, and they both work. I updated my answer with an example that's equivalent to what I'm using. I hope you can get it working too!